# Docker: Attaching to detached container

Tags: docker

I'm trying to attach to a detached container but it seems to freeze and I have to ctrl-c to get back to the shell.

I start my container with this

```
sudo docker run -d -t  mysql /bin/bash
```

and when I try to attach it with

```
sudo docker attach <id>
```

it does nothing but hold onto my shell session.

However, if I start my container with interactive

```
sudo docker run -i -t  mysql /bin/bash
```

and ctrl-p/q to exit and then attach with the command above it works perfectly fine.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `-d` your container runs detached in the background. If you want to interact with it, connect inside this container with `docker exec`, or as you have noticed, run not detached but with -i -t

> > > If I start it in interactive mode and ctrl-p/q, does that put it into detach mode?

No, check the doc docs.docker.com/articles/basics/#running-an-interactive-shel‌​l, extract "o detach the tty without exiting the shell, # use the escape sequence Ctrl-p + Ctrl-q", -t -i means running an interactive container, with a TTY and capture STDIN

Comment: If I start it in interactive mode and ctrl-p/q, does that put it into detach mode?

Comment: No, check the doc http://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/#running-an-interactive-shell, extract "o detach the tty without exiting the shell,
# use the escape sequence Ctrl-p + Ctrl-q", -t -i means running an interactive container, with a TTY and capture STDIN

Comment: +1 - Hello, may I suggest that you edit your accepted answer with the comment you made above ?  It complements the answer well and if included in the answer does not run the risk of being garbage-collected one day somebody decides to clean up comments. Cheers. ;-)